# rake install does not work for octopress

Tags: ruby, rake, octopress

I am trying to setup rake via this doc.

http://octopress.org/docs/setup/

But I get some errors.

```
ikhthiandor@ikhthiandor-Satellite-L450:/opt/octopress$ rake install
## Copying classic theme into ./source and ./sass
mkdir -p source
rake aborted!
Permission denied - source

Tasks: TOP => install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

With sudo I get this output.

```
ikhthiandor@ikhthiandor-Satellite-L450:/opt/octopress$ sudo rake install
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- bundler/setup

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is a list of files in the directory.

```
ikhthiandor@ikhthiandor-Satellite-L450:/opt/octopress$ ls -a
.                   config.ru     .git        Rakefile         .slugignore
..                  _config.yml   .gitignore  .rbenv-version   .themes
CHANGELOG.markdown  Gemfile       plugins     README.markdown
config.rb           Gemfile.lock  .powrc      .rvmrc
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: There was a typo in my question. I meant to say, "I am trying to setup octopress via this doc."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ikhthiandor: Looks like you are a beginner in the ruby/rails world.

By running the `rake install` command, you are installing the default octopress theme using the [rake tool](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/Built-In_Rails_Tools/What_is_Rake_anyway%3F). Not `trying to setup rake` as you mention in the question.

The first error ( `Permission denied - source` when trying `mkdir -p source` - as you correctly guessed - is because the user doesn't have permissions to create that directory.

The second error ( `no such file to load -- bundler/setup` ) is because the previous `install dependencies` steps are not performed correctly (for the user running this command).

The install dependencies steps to be completed successfully are:

```
1. gem install bundler
2. rbenv rehash    # If you use rbenv, rehash to be able to run the bundle command
3. bundle install
```

I am guessing you ran these steps successfully as 'ikhthiandor' user, so the bundler gem is not available for the 'sudo' user.

You can fix this by either of the following options:

1. changing permissions on `/opt/octopress` folder so that 'ikhthiandor' user has rights to create sub-folders/files within.
2. Run all the commands in the [Octopress Setup doc](http://octopress.org/docs/setup/) as 'sudo'

Best practice would be to use either [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) to manage custom installations of ruby environments per user (and not do everything as super user).

If you are indeed a fresher in the ruby-rails world, and want to step up your knowledge of the tools and the best practices in the ruby/rails world, I suggest browsing through the first few chapters of the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) book that is available for free on-line.

HTH

Comment: You are right. I am a beginner in ruby world. Btw, I meant to setup octopress not rake(that was a typo). According to your suggestion I made 'ikhthiandor' as the owner of /opt/octopress. It worked properly then. Thanks for taking the time to reply :)

I started learning ruby from the book by Zed Shaw. I am busy with learning other core stuffs so I have planned to take ruby in small chunks. So, it will take some time to learn the basics of ruby. Once I have grasped the rvm, rbenv stuff I will redo this setup according to the best practice.